# xlsread in Matlab returns NaN even there is no data in Excel

Tags: matlab, nan, xlsread

I use `xlsread` to read a xlsx file. I expect the `rawdata` will return a 34x3 cell array.

```
[raw_num raw_txt rawdata]=xlsread('file.xlsx');
```

The `raw_num` and `raw_txt` return correct value, 34x1 cell array and 34x2 cell array.

However, when I check `rawdata`, it returns 139x6 cell array. It contains not only data in excel file but also `NaN` element. For the `NaN` element, there is no data in excel file. I can only assume that I might type something before and then I delete it. But why matlab read it?

The rawdata looks like this:

> 'a' 'b' 'c' NaN NaN
>
> 'd' 'e' 'f' NaN NaN
>
> NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

How can I avoid this when I use xlsread?

Or how can I remove NaN after I got this matrix?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `NaN` elements are only at the edges of the matrix like shown in your example, you could first remove rows with all `NaN`, then remove the columns with all `NaN`.

```
% test data
A = {NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN; NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN; NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN};
A{1, 1} = 'a';
A{1, 2} = 'b';
A{2, 1} = 'c';
A{2, 2} = 'd';

fh = @(x) all(isnan(x));
% remove rows with all NaN
A(all(cellfun(fh, A),2),:) = [];
% remove columns with all NaN
A(:,all(cellfun(fh, A),1)) = [];
```

The reason you have to do it this way is because `cellfun` does not preserve dimensions, so you have to run it on each dimension individually. Alternatively, you could write a for loop.

Comment: all(cellfun(fh, A)) only returns the logic of NaN at "first row". So when NaN in matrix A is not the same in row and column, this code cannot execute appropriately. For example, I change A to a 3x4 cell: A = {NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN; NaN, NaN, NaN,NaN; NaN, NaN, NaN,NaN};
A{1, 1} = 'a';
A{1, 2} = 'b';
A{2, 1} = 'c';
A{2, 2} = 'd'; then A(all(cellfun(fh, A)),:) = [] will show error

Comment: I think it should be: fh = @(x) all(isnan(x));
a1=cellfun(fh,A);
A(a1(:,1),:)=[]; 
A(:,a1(1,:))=[];

Comment: @chshiu the code you wrote will work only if the non-NaN elements are at the top left of your matrix, but it will fail if there are in the middle, or if there are some rows with NaNs in the middle, etc. Although it is an interesting approach. I'll see now if I can modify it to solve your problem

Comment: I tested your code and my code under the condition that NaN is in the middle. Both work successfully.

Comment: Good, as long as it solves your problem. Try this `A = {NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN; NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN; NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN; NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN; NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN};
A{2, 2} = 'a';
A{2, 3} = 'b';
A{4, 2} = 'c';
A{4, 3} = 'd';`, you will see the problem.

Comment: I got it! Your code only found out whole row or column are NaN. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can remove NaN's like below:

```
k = {'a' 'b' 'c' NaN NaN}
k(cellfun(@isnan, k)) = [] ;
```

Comment: In my case, I was asked to set UniformOutput to false. But when I used "rawdata(cellfun(@isnan, rawdata,'UniformOutput',false)) = [] ;" I got an error: Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'cell'.

Comment: What version you are on?

Comment: matlab is R2015b

Comment: I am on 2015a..it is working fine...try this: k(cellfun(@isnan, k,'un',1)) = []